# Connect Node.js with whatsaap

Tags: node.js

I am new to node. I am making an app where I need some support from whatsaap in terms of getting data from users.Need to connect whastaap with node.js so that i could start off with my development. Any reliable suggestions that could help in development and also scale later would be valuable. Thanks.

Comment: this site is related to asking exact code related problem. Not for offtopic suggestions. Could you please share what you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-wa. This might help. cheers.

Comment: Is this reliable enough?

Comment: @oggy probably not, but AFAIK Whatsapp doesn't have an open API.